How would a planet with both global and hemispherical seasons work?
Long ago, I asked a question on how to make Earth's oceans brackish based on Chris Wayans's super-Earth, Lyr.  Now we're going back to it because it has another interesting detail which results in another question.  According to Wayans, Lyr has an axial tilt of 36 degrees.  If its parameters were a little closer to Earth's, it would still be a warmer planet with more extreme seasons.  But it's got something a little extra--an elliptical orbit, which would result in asymmetrical seasons.  In other worldbuilding projects, fictional worlds usually have one type of seasons or the other.  The fact that Lyr had both inspires this particular scenario:
This alternate world of mine is part of a trinary system of "instars", artificial stars crafted by some hyper-Kardashev civilization.  It orbits two of them, both of which are in the K stage (which is to say, currently on the stage that resembles K-type natural stars).  Those two orange suns, in turn, orbit the third sun, a yellow hypergiant stage.  The planet has an axial tilt of 26.9 degrees, a rotation of 48 hours and a revolution of 728 days, which translates to almost four Earth years.  But its orbit is so elliptical that the length of seasons is as follows:

Spring:  137 days (three-quarters of one Earth year)
Summer:  365 days (two whole Earth years)
Autumn  136 days
Winter:  88 days (almost half an entire Earth year)

So we've got ourselves an artificially habitable world with a higher axial tilt and less circular orbit than Earth, which means it has both hemispherical and global seasons.  But would the two types of seasons be in sync?  If not, then how would the overlap look?  Would you get a hemispherical winter in a global summer, or vice versa?

They will have about the same periods, but not necessarily in sync
Earth actually does this, just not very noticably.  In Early-January every year, the Earth is closest to the sun, and in Early July it is farthest meaning that the Northern Hemisphere as a whole gets slightly milder Summers and Winters than the Southern Hemisphere.
An Elliptical orbit is generally a repeating pattern.  It can shift slightly from year to year due to the gravity of other planets, but this shift is very slow and not very noticable.  Likewise, axial tilt is more or less the same year after year.  So, you elliptical and axial seasons are both roughly controlled by the planet's position in its orbit meaning a year in one is also a year in the other.
What is not guaranteed is if they will line up with each other in any given way.  Your planet could be such that your elliptical winter & summer are in close sync with Axial winter and summer like here on Earth, but it is equally possible that they are displaced so the your Axial winter/summer are in your elliptical Autumn/Spring. If they are aligned together, then what you will have is one hemisphere with very mild seasons, and the other hemisphere with very strong seasonal variance.  But if they are staggered, it means that both hemispheres are characterized by long somewhat mild winters/summers with very short Autumn/Spring cycles.

